# how can I output ' ' with using print in python

Tags: python, string

```
print('{0:^10}'.format('hi'))        output -    hi 
'{0:^10}'.format('hi')               output -'   hi    '
```

Can I output the first sentence like the second one by using the `print` function?

Comment: Escape the ' with \ like: `print(' \' ')`.

Comment: You mean without using the `format` function?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you just need to escape your single `'`s by putting a backslash `\` before them - this is called string escaping and helps your `print` function to notice, that these characters should be displayed as plain text and not be interpreted like usual, "special" characters.

Answer (score 1):

Or Just enclose in double quotes

```
print("'{0:^10}'".format("hi"))
```

Comment: modified the answer

Comment: Oh,, it was so simple.. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) which for strings returns a representation of the literal you would use to create the string:

```
>>> print(repr('{0:^10}'.format('hi')))
'    hi    '
```

There are other ways to do it, with or without backslash:

```
>>> print('\'{0:^10}\''.format('hi'))
'    hi    '
>>> print("'{0:^10}'".format('hi'))
'    hi    '
```

But I think for using `repr` is the clearest and more general way.

Comment: exactly what I wanted!! Thank you so much! How do I call repr?

Comment: @DongHyeokKim Just like I did in my answer.

Comment: repr is the only thing to output like that? or Is there any way using backslash? ?

Comment: @DongHyeokKim Sure, see my edit. But what's the point? Backslash are ugly.

Comment: @DongHyeokKim And mixing single and double quotes is inconsistent. And if the string you want to print contains double quotes you need backslashes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `repr`

```
>>> print('\'{0:^10}\''.format('hi'))
'    hi    '
```